# 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: malformed \N character escape

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to push data from Databricks into SQL. However, I get the following error:

[image]

I noticed in the file that I am processing that one of the columns has the following as a value:

[image]

I have tried to filter out the records by using the following:

```
df = df.filter(df.COLUMN != "\N")
```

However, when the above runs, I get the error message idenitfied above. Is there some way to filter out values that have an escape character in them?

I would really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggested, you need to escape the backslash `\`

```py
df.filter(df.value != "\\N")
```